# Different Farm and DLL versions

Tags: 2007, versioning, configuration-wizard, patching

I was trying to add a new Content DB to my SharePoint farm when I encountered an error

> The specified SPConfigurationDatabase has been upgraded to a newer version of SharePoint. Please upgrade this SharePoint application server before attempting to access this object.

Central admin shows that my Farm version is different than server versions. Farm version is 12.0.0.6608 and server versions are 12.0.0.6421 (SP2). I checked the installed updates on all servers but there are no CU's installed.

When I checked the DB for entries in Version table of Config DB, there is an entry for the fore-said version. Wanted to check how did my config DB got upgraded to a later version when my servers are still at SP2?

Comment: There should be a file Upgrade.log in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\LOGS. It will tell you more when and how has that happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the PSConfig.exe utility on each server, this should sort out the mismatch.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Since my Config DB version is 12.0.0.6608 and server versions are 12.0.0.6421, will it kickoff a patch upgrade of servers? I guess 6608 is SP3. if so, I may need to take the backup of my dbs first and eventually it will be a upgrade project in itself. Thought?